# How in R can I combine two groups of data and add them each into single columns after parsing?

Tags: r, parsing, variables, multiple-columns, data-manipulation

```
library(rvest)

link1 <- "https://somon.tj/adv/7866644_5-komn-kvartira-3-etazh-79-m2-a-sino/"
link2 <- "https://somon.tj/adv/7985721_2-komn-dom-grandzavod/"

house_link <- c(link1, link2)

house_features = lapply(houselink, function(link) {
  page_data <- 
tryCatch({
    read_html(link)
    pricing = page_data %>% html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text(trim = T)}, 
error = function(e) e, 
warning = function(w) w)

  
  if(!inherits(page_data, "error")) {
    data.frame(
      link = link,
      parameters = page_data %>% html_nodes(".label") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE),
      values = page_data %>% html_nodes(".info") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
    )
    list(
      pricing = page_data %>% html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text(trim = T)
    )
  } else {
    NULL
  }
})
```

But when I use the `do.call(rbind)`, it produces an error.

```
do.call(rbind, house_features) %>% 
  group_by(link, parameters) %>%
  mutate(parameters = if_else(row_number() > 1, paste(parameters,row_number()), parameters)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = link, names_from = parameters, values_from = values)
```

While one of the links has 19 variables, while the second one contains 5 variables only. You see the discrepancy. How can I make all variables each into individual columns? If it has no value on that variable, say, additional 14 variables, I want to add NA for the value of the variables. How should I accomplish this, peeps?

Comment: You want to essentially `rbind` them while staying aware of column names? `dplyr::union_all` does that

Comment: You mean, `union_all(parameters, values)`?

Comment: You need to remove `return(house_features) ` from `for` loop. Using `return` halts the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

1. Gather the house features in a list

```
house_features = lapply(house_link, function(link) {
  page_data <- tryCatch(read_html(link),error = function(e) e ,warning=function(w) w)

  if(!inherits(page_data, "error")) {
    data.frame(
      link = link,
      parameters = page_data %>% html_nodes(".label") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE),
      values = page_data %>% html_nodes(".info") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
    )
  } else {
    NULL
  }
})
```

2. `rbind` them using `do.call`, ensure that the parameter names are unique (they are not / for example link1 has two parameters called `Floor`), and then `pivot_wider`

```
do.call(rbind,house_features) %>% 
  group_by(link, parameters) %>%
  mutate(parameters = if_else(row_number()>1, paste(parameters,row_number()), parameters)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = link, names_from=parameters,values_from=values)
```

Output:

```
  link   `Type of offer` Category House  Floor Area  Condition Internet Toilet Gas   `Front door` Parking Furniture `Floor 2` `Ceiling height` Security Other `Possibility of…
  <chr>  <chr>           <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>        <chr>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>            <chr>    <chr> <chr>           
1 https… from owner      elite    monol… 9 fl… 107 … european… optics   2 bat… trunk armored      parking fully fu… laminate  3 m.             bars on… plas… no              
2 https… from agent      NA       panel… NA    255 … NA        NA       NA     NA    NA           NA      NA        NA        NA               NA       NA    NA              
# … with 4 more variables: Possibility of getting a mortgage <chr>, Possibility of exchange <chr>, Number of floors <chr>, Heating <chr>
```

Comment: How can I avoid errors along the way, dear @langtang? If the link breaks in the process, and it was changed. How can I move to the next link, if I ask.

Comment: perhaps wrap in `try_catch()` - see my edit?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am expanding my code from simplified version. And experimenting right now. I wish stackoverflow would have had a mobile app. Thanks a lot, you're a legend.

Comment: What if I add one more variable called pricing. It copies itself. How can I add that properly, @langtang? \n By the way, I revised my code in the question.

Comment: hmm, I think we are encouraged to ask new questions, rather than continuing build on the same

Comment: Can you post as a new question, and I'll try to answer? Or maybe others will have better ideas

Comment: @AkbarAto, I think that pricing is constant for each `link` correct?  If so, in the lapply, add it as a the fourth element of your data.frame (i.e. data.frame(link=..., parameters=..., values=..., pricing = ...)`, and then later in the pivot wider, add it to `id_cols`, like this: `id_cols = c("link", "pricing")`

Answer (score 0):

```
house_data <- do.call(rbind, house_features) %>% 
  group_by(link, parameters) %>%
  mutate(parameters = if_else(row_number() > 1, paste(parameters,row_number()), parameters)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(link, pricing,), names_from = parameters, values_from = values)
```

What I found?
Although the variable `pricing` may cause repetition and redundancy across data frame as you would see, still--surprisingly--`lapply` function works rapidly with an astonishing speed compared with a traditional for-loop!

You've got a whole ball of wax, I mean. Thanks @langtang :)